# set line-increment in nl command to a float number

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to use nl command to do numbering for lines. Is it possible to set line-increment in nl command to a float number.

I know that we cant use -i switch to set line-increment like this:

```
$ cat test | nl  -i 2
    1   #! /bin/bash
    3   for dir in dir1 dir2
    5   do
```

but it doesn't work for float numbers like:

```
$ cat test | nl  -i 0.1
  nl: invalid line number increment: ‘0.1’
```

I want the output to be like this

```
1   #! /bin/bash
1.1 for dir in dir1 dir2
1.2 do
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could use awk instead

```
awk '{print 0.9+(x=x+.1) FS $0}' file
```

With padding (up to 99999 lines, for more add higher number in printf)

```
awk '{printf "%-7.1f%s\n",0.9+(x=x+.1),$0}'
```

Comment: @KarolyHorvath How do you mean, like between the number and line ?

Comment: No, between the moon and the earth... what else?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Just making sure! Depending on how many lines though it would always mess up. Unless i read the file twice i suppose...

Comment: Well, you can just do what `nl` does, and use a large enough one (for all practical purposes). The OP's question suggests your approach, but I *really* doubt he thought it through.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Can you pad both sides with printf ? Otherwise that's all i've got... :(